# How do you add nodes to a linear linked list? [java]

Tags: linked-list, addition, nodes, binary-search-tree, pool

So basically, while I'm not new to this, I've somewhat forgotten the set up for adding nodes to a linear linked list. Basically, I have a cap for the number of nodes that I can add, and currently, I have:

"storage" is a binary tree with ONLY next nodes.

```
private void addToStorage(Node node){
    if(storage.size() <= maxSize) // Current Size of storage
    {
        node.data = null;
        node.prev = null;
        node.next = storage;
        storage = node;
    }
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement this function? If not, how should I go about doing it using a similar method?

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you are able to retrieve the last node stored somewhere inside that storage object or from somewere else:

```
add(Node node) {
   if(prevNode != null)
       prevNode.next = node;
   node.prev = prevNode;
   node.next = null;
}
```

Also, there's no point of nulling the data since it's usually set before calling add.

Comment: Oh, I meant that I'm adding items to the storage object here.